# jQuery Orbit Plugin

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have come across something rather strange with this slider I'm using called Orbit. I have searched here and Google, but none seem to pinpoint my problem.

I have set the width and the height of the #featured element, yet on occasion the featured element appears to completely collapse in on itself, despite having content (I.e. Images) within the element. When I say on occasion I mean, one minute it will work perfectly fine the next it's completely collapsed leaving only the navigation arrows in show.

I have tried fooling around with the CSS to try to combat this problem, but all to no avail. So I come to you guys and your keen eyes. Am I missing something completely stupid or is it more serious?

### Orbit Wrap Css

```
/* orbit id and slider size */

 #featured {
    width: 720px;
    height: 380px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #000;
    background-image: url(../assets/orbit/loading.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
  }

#featured>img,  
#featured>div,
#featured>a { display: none; }

/* CONTAINER */

div.orbit-wrapper {
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    position: relative; }

div.orbit {
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden }

div.orbit>img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: none; }

div.orbit>a {
    border: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    line-height: 0; 
    display: none; }

.orbit>div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; }

/* Note: If your slider only uses content or anchors, you're 
going to want to put the width and height declarations on 
the ".orbit>div" and "div.orbit>a" tags in addition to just 
the .orbit-wrapper */
```

### Orbit HTML

```
<!-- ꜜꜜ orbit gallery ꜜꜜ -->
<div id="featured">  
    <img src="assets/img/g-backing.jpg" />
    <img src="assets/img/scandal- (1).jpg" />
    <img src="assets/img/scandal- (2).jpg" />
    <img src="assets/img/scandal- (3).jpg" />
    <img src="assets/img/scandal- (4).jpg" />
</div>
```

Here's the original Site location of the Orbit slider, so you can see what it is I have built. **[(Orbit Slider)](http://zurb.com/playground/orbit-jquery-image-slider)**

Comment: have you tried adding `min-height` or `min-width` to the `#feature` element?

Comment: I have tried that along with editing the source script file. to change the height ratios. Still no luck. I have scince moved to another plugin and am working on that.